# Form - button which go to next page

Tags: database, ms-access

I made form on ms-acces. I put function "pages" to my form, then i made some page (for example page 1, page 2 and page 3). On each page is some content but on this example we do not care what is on page(s). I want make button on page 1, which i click and go automaticlly to page 2.

I tried short line of code but it does not work so i do not know how can i solve this problem on easy way. 
Karta_projektu is my whole form.

```
Private Sub Polecenie426_Click()
    Forms!Karta_projektu.GoToPage (1)
End Sub
```

I want make button which let me go from page 1 to page 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about pages on a tabcontrol:

To go to a specific page, you just set the value on a tabcontrol:

```
Private Sub Polecenie426_Click()
    Me!TabControlName.Value = 1 'Page 2 since pages start at 0
End Sub
```

I recommend using page names to navigate, however. If you just use page position, you need to adjust all code after adding/removing/re-ordering pages.

```
Private Sub Polecenie426_Click()
    Me!TabControlName.Value = Me!PageName.PageIndex 'Go to page PageName
End Sub
```